# Audio html tag can't fast forward or rewind control

Tags: html, audio, header, fast-forward, rewind

I'm using audio html tag to load the audio from my upload server, and I don't know what's the reason why my audio can't loop, fast forward or rewind control as usual.

My audio: http://vmeet.world-telephone.com/m2/x.php?f=1682667950&x=1

The header:

```
Accenpt-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4707216
Content-Range:bytes 0-4707215/4707216
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Thu, 18 Dec 2014 16:45:24 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) PHP/5.3.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1j
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29
```

Please tell me how to fix it, thanks so much

Comment: Could you share your HTML and JS script, please?

Comment: Do your files have reading permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typo when configuring the server. Change `Accenpt-Ranges` to `Accept-Ranges`.

`Header set Accept-Ranges bytes` for Apache 2.x `mod_headers` in `httpd.conf`.

`server.range-requests = "enable"` for Lighttpd.

The `Status Code` should update to `206` then.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ms1S.png