# Spring controller returns bytes of an audio file: html audio player can't fast forward or rewind

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this controller that is supposed to return a part of an audio file (for testing, I made it return all bytes in the file):

```java
@GetMapping("/voice")
@CrossOrigin
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> streamBytes(
        @RequestParam(name = "name") String name) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/static/" +
            calculatePath(name)).getFile());

    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    int numBytes = fileContent.length;
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("audio/mpeg"))
            .body(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, 0, numBytes));
}
```

The path to this controller is used in an

```
<audio id='audioPlayer' src='controllerPath'></audio>
```

The sound is loaded correctly, however the audio player doesn't allow fast forward or rewind. If I use a direct URL to the file (since, the file is in `resources/static/file.mp3`) - `http://localhost:8082/file.mp3`, I can fast forward and rewind just fine.

Also when I tried changing `HttpStatus.OK` to `HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT` the player completely refused to play the file.

What is it with the current controller code that prevents fast forward and rewind?

Comment: I don't see where your controller would accept the input which part of the file it should serve for fast forward or reverse. Found this question for the relevant header(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551737/audio-html-tag-cant-fast-forward-or-rewind-control

Comment: Thanks. I saw that question, but it didn't occur that it would apply to me. Now it turned out that the `Accept-Ranges` header is obligatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the return statement to

```
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("audio/mpeg"))
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .body(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, 0, numBytes));
```

^ added the `.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")` part. Now the fast forward and rewind works as expected!

Comment: The answer that was linked in the comments to my question, says status code 206 should be returned, but it seems to be working fine with 200 status code...